# How To Find the Locale in Sybase?

Tags: database, sybase, locale

I have some servers in Europe and some in Asia.
I would like to be able to work out where the current server is by querying ... something.

Is there some global variable I can query or sp_xxx I can execute to find out the locale of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a parameter in a table.

There can be multiple solutions to the problem, though, and they may or may not work depending on a number of factors. For example, is there any difference in the database server or operating system configuration which could tell one location from the other?

Answer (score 2):

```
sp_helpsort
```

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs143.htm

Will show you the sort order and character set of the system

Answer (score 0):

If the dataserver is properly configured for XP calls, you can execute

```
 xp_cmdshell 'domainname'
```

which will allow you to get the output of the OS 'domainname' command.  You can then parse that to determine your locale.